# Change nodes position through scripts

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I'm Creating some nodes through python script. The problem is that all the nodes are overlapping each over. I just wanna programatically re position those nodes. How to do this?

```py
 imgtx1 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
 imgtx2 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
```

Just consider these 2 nodes as of now. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every node has it's own size/location properties that are accessible in the node itself.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

imgtx1 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
imgtx2 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')

#location
imgtx1.location = Vector((200.0, 400.0))

#or
imgtx2.location.x = 100
imgtx2.location.y = 200

#size
# only width changes are allowed within the values of 
# node.bl_width_min and node.bl_width_max
imgtx2.width = 200
imgtx2.width_hidden = 100
```

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks a lot! @Secrop

Comment: If I use `newmat.location = Vector(500,100)` I get `NameError: name 'Vector' is not defined`. `newmat.location.x = -200` works though.

Comment: @edna, you need to ```import mathutils```... I'll correct the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating. In 2.80 I found that I don't need it actually. `imgtx2.location = -300, 150` works fine.